# Running flutter app on mobile via USB cable but appears black screen only

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-application, mobile-app-testing

Here is the message i get when i run flutter app on my android mobile and also i see just black screen on my mobile, though the app gets installed i can see icon of that

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A217F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Note: C:\Users\RK\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\local_auth_android-1.0.19\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\localauth\LocalAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54767/IQmQ4n-nj04=/ws
Syncing files to device SM A217F...
I/xample.untitle(22299): Compiler allocated 4564KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
E/flutter (22299): 
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
E/flutter (22299): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:134:11)
E/flutter (22299): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22299): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (22299): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22299): #2      main (package:untitled/main.dart:15:3)
E/flutter (22299): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22299):
```

```
I tried to run app on mobile via usb, my developer mode is ON, app runs in chrome web well but when i move to mobile through usb i get only black blank screen.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution for appearing dark screen is go to file, open then select project and open android part of it... now run this one it opens app in mobile(android)